# Android Studio Quickboot/Snapshot not supported error?

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0, android-studio-3.6.1

I am Facing this error recently. Everything was fine i was learning android studio and suddenly out of nowhere this hit me up.

****Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.****

This error made me to delete my virtual device and create a new one. Then it became too slow to start and run the applications. I am running an i5 - 4570 with 8 gigs of ram and a NVIDIA GT 610. I have installed HAXM and virtualization is enabled.Please help me through this.

Kudos.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that your CPU do not have right configuration the INTEL VTX technology in your PC.

Android recommend this steps:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device

Is more reliable in some cases use a physical device via USB instead of emulator.

Comment: But it was working fine before. Mine is an i5-4570 and it supports VT-x.